# Web Forms and PHP

Tags: php, arrays, webforms

I'm trying to add a new animal to an array using an HTML form and then display the contents of the array each time the user enters a new animal. Here's the code I have so far. It works, it's just not adding a new animal, to the list, each time I hit the submit button. It just replaces the last one entered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
What is your favorite animal?<br>
<input type="text" name="text" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Animal" />
</form>

<h2>Animal List</h2>

<?php
echo $_POST['text'];
?>
</body>
```

Comment: There are dozens of ways to solve this issue, however, since you are a student, you are only allowed to use material that was taught. You will need to find a way to store entered information into either a **hidden** field in your webpage, store it in some sort of **session** variable, or store information in file on disk and **append** data to file each time a new information is given.

Comment: Has you teacher covered SESSIONS yet?

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Quentin You are quite right, but as this student only seems to have done Day1 of the course, it might be a little premature to hit them with this little wrinkle :) Maybe wait until tahy have got to Day5 :) :)

Comment: A better question "title" and initial search attempt would have "[php form submit add to list](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20form%20submit%20add%20to%20list)" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

the $_POST array doesn't save values, each time you submit the form the page refreshes and a new set of values is passed to the array.  You could save the values to a `$_SESSION by saying $_SESSION['animals'][]=$_POST['text']` and then loop through the session each time to print out the values.

It's not really something you would do in production I don't think, as I think you'd usually save the data into your database to do something with, but of course I don't know what your end goal is :) but I guess you are trying to learn an idea/concept so there's a solution of sorts.

You could also add a hidden input to build it up, I can't remember exactly but something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
foreach($_POST['text'] as $animal) {
echo '<input type="hidden" name="text[]" value="' . $animal . '"/>';

}
```

will create a bunch of hidden inputs with the current values, then when you click submit for the new value you will have an array of values for 'text'
 which you can then loop through to echo out.

Comment: Sessions has been mentioned but we're not covering it in this assignment. We're discussing arrays.